# A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType does not declare a navigation property with the name in inherited collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have class Student

```
class Student 
{ 
    public virtual MySpecificCollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; } 
}
```

and a specific collection class

```
public class MySpecificCollection<T> : IPropertyCollection<T>{
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}}
```

interface `IPropertyCollection`:

```
public interface IPropertyCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T> {}
```

When i do this

```
var res=Students.Include("Payments");
```

That error occurs

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType does not declare a navigation property with the name in inherited collection

Why this error occurs and how can i fix that without removing my interfaces i classes?  (There is no all codes.)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think this will work. How does EF know how to create a `MySpecificCollection<T>`? I think you're going to have to use an entity class that uses `IEnumerable<T>` and project that to the class with the custom collection type.

Comment: This won't work, navigation properties have to be of type ICollection<T> (or any derived type)

Comment: I need implement IPropertyCollection<T> from ICollection<T> or MySpecificCollection<T> from ICollection<T> or both works?

Comment: and what about IQuerable<T> collection?